# How to create a file in Linux from terminal window?

Tags: linux, bash, file, command-line-interface

What's the easiest way to create a file in Linux terminal?

Comment: `$>newfile` also can create file.

Answer (score 674, accepted):

Depending on what you want the file to contain:

- `touch /path/to/file` for an empty file
- `somecommand > /path/to/file` for a file containing the output of some command.

  ```
    eg: grep --help > randomtext.txt
        echo "This is some text" > randomtext.txt
  ```
- `nano /path/to/file` or `vi /path/to/file` (or `any other editor emacs,gedit etc`)
  It either opens the existing one for editing or creates & opens the empty file to enter, if it doesn't exist

Comment: also, `printf "some long message\nwith newlines\n" > file` . Good luck to all.

Comment: UNIX is not a command line environment, but a family of (very different) OSes. That said: Yes, this should work on most Unices

Comment: `touch` will work in UNIX, because it's a standard tool. The `somecommand` example will work because it uses standard syntax. The `nano` sample may not work because an editor named `nano` may not be installed (nano is not standardized). The standard editor is `ed` and could be used in place of `nano`, or you could use `$EDITOR` to use your user- or system-configured default text editor, if there is one.

Comment: Additionally, you could simply say `>/path/to/file` to create an empty file, even if you don't have `touch`.

Comment: @EugenRieck What if it says permission denied

Comment: "permission denied" means just that - you do not have the permission to create the specified file. This is typically a good thing.

Comment: Also keep in mind, the /dir/ needs to exist for touch/vi(m)/nano to work...at least in certain distros such as CentOS.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the tilde (~) shorthand for the home directory will not be interpreted by a bash script. This tripped me up for a few minutes.

Comment: If you see a 'permission denied' error try:  sudo bash -c 'echo "Text" > file'

Comment: expanding on @ammills01's comment: If you see a 'permission denied' error try any of the commands listed in the question and the above comments with a leading `sudo `, e.g. `sudo touch /path/to/file`. You will then have to type the password to then be given permission (root access) to create this new file

Comment: @EugenRieck: nano seems doesn't work. I tried on Fedora 27 terminal. Got error bash: nano: command not found...

Comment: @vinsinraw That just means, that `nano` is not installed on this system. Most likely `vi` is, so `vi /path/to/file` should work (or just do `yum install nano`)

Comment: Which command does not *`touch`* any file? `mkdir` refuses to create a new directory, so I imagined a command such as `mkfile`.

Comment: @neverMind9 `touch` can be used as `mkfile` - so there must be something else going on. What's the error message to `mkdir` ?

Answer (score 155):

Use [touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix))

```
touch filename
```

Answer (score 133):

**Create the file using `cat`**

`$ cat > myfile.txt`

Now, just type whatever you want in the file:

`Hello World!`

CTRL-D to save and exit

Comment: I prefer using cat since it offers an easy and convenient way to edit the file immediately.

Comment: You can also type nothing.

Comment: When I tried `cat /etc/systemd/system/sample.service`, it said "no such file or directory" rather than creating a new sample.service file.

Comment: @TylerH `cat /etc/systemd/system/sample.service` prints the file to the console `cat > /etc/systemd/system/sample.service` redirects standard input to the file (which is why you need to close standard input by pressing control-d.

Answer (score 53):

There are several possible solutions:

#### Create an empty file

```
touch file

>file

echo -n > file

printf '' > file
```

The `echo` version will work only if your version of `echo` supports the `-n` switch to suppress newlines. This is a non-standard addition. The other examples will all work in a POSIX shell.

#### Create a file containing a newline and nothing else

```
echo '' > file

printf '\n' > file
```

This is a valid "text file" because it ends in a newline.

#### Write text into a file

```
"$EDITOR" file

echo 'text' > file

cat > file <<END \
text
END

printf 'text\n' > file
```

These are equivalent. The `$EDITOR` command assumes that you have an interactive text editor defined in the EDITOR environment variable and that you interactively enter equivalent text. The `cat` version presumes a literal newline after the `\` and after each other line. Other than that these will all work in a POSIX shell.

Of course there are many other methods of writing and creating files, too.

Answer (score 27):

Also, create an empty file:

```
touch myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use `touch` command, as the others said:

```
touch filename
```

To write on file on command line, you can use `echo` or `printf`:

```
echo "Foo" > filename
printf "Foo" > filename
```

Maybe you can have problems with permissions. If you are getting the following error: `bash: filename: Permission denied`, you need to use `sudo bash -c 'echo "Foo" > filename'`, as described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/103643/cannot-echo-hello-x-txt-even-with-sudo

Comment: Or `sudo !!` If you get that error. Using `!!` Will let you rerun the command that failed prepending ‘ `sudo` to the command. Just a tip I find to be very useful. Happy coding =)

Answer (score 19):

How to create a text file on Linux:

- Using `touch` to create a text file: `$ touch NewFile.txt`
- Using `cat` to create a new file: `$ cat NewFile.txt`
  The file is created, but it's empty and still waiting for the input from the user. You can type any text into the terminal, and once done CTRL-D will close it, or CTRL-C will escape you out.
- Simply using `>` to create a text file: `$ > NewFile.txt`
- Lastly, we can use any text editor name and then create the file, such as:
  `nano MyNewFile 
   vi MyNewFile 
   NameOfTheEditor NewFileName`

Answer (score 17):

haha! it's easy! try this:

```
$ touch filename
```

Comment: This worked with sudo, so I was able to create new file in system folder.

Answer (score 16):

This will create an empty file with the current timestamp

```
touch filename
```

Answer (score 16):

***1st method***

```
echo -n > filename.txt
```

***2nd method***

```
> filename.txt
```

***3rd method***

```
touch filename.txt
```

**To view the file contents**

```
vi filename.txt
```

Comment: 2 method  is       type->                      "> filename.txt"

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 16):

```
touch filename
```

for `permission denied` error use `sudo` command as:

```
sudo touch filename
```

Answer (score 11):

Simple as that :

`> filename`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `touch` command to create a new empty file.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_touch.htm

Answer (score 6):

I like the [nano](http://goo.gl/rDgQw) command-line editor (text):

```
nano filename
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you guys are trying to create a new file, but it says: `'File does not exist'`, it's simply because you are also accessing a directory, which does not exist yet. You have to create all non existent directories first, using the `mkdir /path/to/dir` command.

Answer (score 2):

To create a blank file with ownership and permissions using install.

```
sudo install -v -oUSER -gGROUP -m640 /dev/null newFile.txt
```

Comment: The `sudo` is useful in many scenarios, but not directly part of the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: It is needed if you are not the user name that you need the file owned by or not a member of the group.

Comment: Yes, there are scenarios like that which are however strictly speaking not what the OP asked.

Comment: This is actually the answer I came here to find!

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way and quick

```
$ vim filename
```