# What command makes a new file in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command, windows-shell

If **mkdir** creates a new directory, what creates a new file? for example "something.text".

I tried couple of commands mkdir (FileName) -- works fine. But I didn't know how to create a new file inside a directory. I know that I can always go to my project folder then create my new file but I want to know how to do that using terminal to increase productivity.

Comment: try `touch something.text`, creates a new file if it doesn't exist or updates the modification time to the current time if the file exists already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file in Linux from terminal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381463/how-to-create-a-file-in-linux-from-terminal-window)

Comment: you cant do it by command in Windows OS while you can do it in Linux.

Comment: `> someDirectory/someFile`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

On Linux there are mutiple options

The typical used one is **touch**

```
touch bar.txt
```

However you may also use echo if you want to create and write to the file right away

The following command tells to create bar.txt and put foo inside of it

```
echo foo > bar.txt
```

You may also use **>>** which appends to an existing file

The following command puts bar at the end of bar.txt, in a other words, bar will display after foo inside bar.txt

```
echo bar >> bar.txt
```

Comment: Thanks very much. i tried touch but it did not work. then tried echo and stored a value inside and it did work.

Comment: Nice, this also works for word documents like `touch bar.docx`. Would have been nice if this worked for rtf files as well in MAC instead of remembering a different command

Answer (score 5):

You can either use `touch`:

```
$ touch something.txt
```

or `>` operator to redirect *nothing* to a file and effectively creating it:

```
$ > something.txt
```

or

```
$ : > something.txt
```

Note that last 2 commands will *truncate* file contents if file already exists.

Comment: thanks for the replay but none has worked , am using the terminal inside of code editor if it help . i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean on Linux so the command is touch.

Comment: thanks for the replay, but no am using a code editor in windows and touch did not work

Comment: Please tag your postings properly. When you tag it with *shell*, people will assume that you are looking for a solution running in a Posix-compliant shell, and from this will conclude that you either are on Unix, Linux, Cygwin or something similar.